# Question about the terms and operations in basic division

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory

Let's pretend that I am a child and you want to teach me division.  You demonstrate through an example division as repeated subtraction.

This is the simple algorithm the child learns from your lesson:

```
n=0
remainder=dividend
if(dividend == divisor) return 1;
while(remainder > divisor) {
  n = n + 1;
  remainder=remainder - divisor; 
}
println "Whole portion: ", n, " with remainder ", remainder, "/", divisor
```

There is a bug in that algorithm.  See if you can spot it.

Here is the revised version:

```
n=0
remainder=dividend
assert(divisor != 0);
if(dividend == divisor) return 1;
while(remainder > divisor) {
  n = n + 1;
  remainder=remainder - divisor; 
}
println "Whole portion: ", n, " with remainder ", remainder, "/", divisor
```

In this version if you try to divide by zero, the system fails.

There is a different way to fix the bug though.  The bug was an infinite loop, btw, if you didn't notice, because remainder would never decrease when the divisor was zero.

```
n=0
remainder=dividend
if(dividend == divisor) return 1;
while( (n==0 && n>divisor) && remainder > divisor) {
  n = n + 1; 
  remainder=remainder - divisor; 
}
println "Whole portion: ", n, " with remainder ", remainder, "/", divisor
```

So for example, if you divide 3/8 you get:

```
Whole portion: 0 with remainder 3/8
```

If you try to divide 3/0 you get:

```
Whole portion: 0 and 3/0 remaining.
```

What am I doing wrong in the third example?  Isn't dividing by zero asking for a fractional number < 0?

Isn't that just a special kind of complex number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division by zero is undefined and the result of the operation is not a number, neither real nor complex.

Division by zero can sometimes be represented by limits, e.g.
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x^2 = +\infty, \text{ but }
\lim_{x \to 0^+} 1/x = +\infty  \text{ while }
\lim_{x \to 0^-} 1/x = -\infty,
$$
so the 2-sided limit would be undefined in the latter case.

Comment: So the response could be NaN instead of an assertion?

Comment: @JustinSwanhart NaN is from programming :) and indeed the IEEE floating standard defines $x/0$ as `Inf` for $x>0$ or `-Inf` for $x<0$ or `NaN` for $x=0$.

Comment: I'm developing a system that can store and do math like humans do, so I'm making sure everything works using the simplest algorithms possible before optimizing.  This is also helping me relearn my basic math skills.  I am also using a base 2^32 abacus internally.  If you think humans are fast with a base10 abacus you should see a computer with a base 2^32 one.